# C# datagrid/datatable вернуться на определенную запись

Tags: c#, winforms

Такой вопрос.
Есть dataTable привязан к DataGrid Язык C# WinForm

Я кликаю на нужную запись и обрабатываю ее. Для себя запоминаю ее ID. Есть в ней допустим такое поле.
Условный код

```
         DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)datagrid1.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show($"{dataRowView["ID"]}");
```

Обрабатываю запись как мне нужно. Допустим это занимает время.
Я возвращаюсь в основной grid и делаю перезагрузку всей таблицы. Перечитываю таблицу с сервера.Пока я работал с одной записью. В эту таблицу кто то уже мог повносить другие записи и мне нужно их увидеть. НО!! Курсор нужно вернуть на ту запись на которой я был.  Я помню ее ID Но ее INDEX естественно изменился.
Я пока для себя написал код, который методом перебора ищет нужное мне значение и вычисляет Index и возвращает курсор на нужную мне запись.
Условный код

```
            var i = 0;
            foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                if ( row["ID"].ToString() == "50" )
                {
                    datagrid1.SelectedIndex = i;
                    datagrid1.Focus();
                }
                i++;
            }
```

Я обернул его в отдельную функцию.
То что мне нужно работает.. но некрасиво.
Методом перебора это как то звучит не оптимизировано.
Как вернуть курсор на нужную мне запись по значению определенной колонки, наиболее правильным способом?
без перебора. Колонка содержит уникальное поле.
Запись выделяется всегда только одна. Выделяется вся запись. SingleRow

Спасибо.

Comment: Обычно после рефреш этим не заморачиваться, потому что нет гарантий что он будет в гриде вообще. Возьмите к примеру проводник, сделайте рефреш и посмотрите что к чему

Comment: @Aziz Umarov Да нет гарантий. После удаления например. Но тогда код не найдет запись и останется на первой записи. Так и работает сейчас. Это устраивает. Но от перебора все таки хочу отказаться. Вопрос в силе. Предполагаем что запись будет.

Comment: Попробуйте так если получится то напишу ответ
DataGrid.SelectedIndex = DataGrid.Items.Select((item, index) => new {item, index}).First(condition).index;

Comment: где кондишен  (item=> item["ID"].toString() == "50")

Comment: @Aziz Umarov пока не получается. У winform datagridview нет метода SelectedIndex. Это у WPF форм. Я немного не тот кусок кода написал. Экспериментировал winform и wpf. Грубо говоря мне нужно получить индекс записи(row) по значению заданной колонки не используя перебор. По индексу я выделю нужную запись.

Comment: Смотрите на такой пример. this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode =
        DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;

Comment: Так вот вам нужно найти индекс в дата сете и выделить нужный row

Comment: Вы действительно используете [DataGrid](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8) или всё-таки [DataGridView](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netcore-3.1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, код говорит сам за себя.

- Задаю первичный ключ для `DataTable` **table**
- Нахожу `DataRow` с этим ключом
- Определяю ее индекс
- Выделяю строчку в `DataGridView` **dataGridView1** с этим индексом

```csharp
// Это можно сделать 1 раз после загрузки данных в DataTable
table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { table.Columns["ID"] };

// Ключ точно string? Если число, уберите здесь кавычки.
DataRow row = table.Rows.Find("50"); 
int i = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
```

Или выделить одной страшной строкой можно

```csharp
dataGridView1.Rows[table.Rows.IndexOf(table.Rows.Find("50"))].Selected = true;
```

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно. Работает.. ключ конечно не стринговый. Это были наброски по быстрому.

Comment: единственное, что .Select строку выделяет, но не прокручивает к ней если строка за прокруткой грида. Но этот вопрос решил через  dataGridView1.CurrentCell =  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];   И взял Ваше i

Comment: @Manul74 - для прокрутки грида можно использовать свойство [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex)