# Соответствие Index DataTbale и dataGridView (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

в продолжении темы [C# datagrid/datatable вернуться на определенную запись](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1148423/c-datagrid-datatable-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c)
Где я получил ответ и все работает. Но есть нюанс если таблица в dataGridView отфильтрована

Есть Таблица которая загружена в dataGridView
в таблице например 10 записей.

Но в dataGridView фильтром я показываю только 5 из них.
Пример фильтра

```
           DataView dv;
            dv = new DataView(DS.Tables["Orders"], "Type = 2 ", "Type Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

Мне нужно работать с одной определенной записью. Я знаю ее индекс в таблице. Но ее индекс в dataGridView
другой.  Узнать даблкликом оригинальный индекс таблицы я могу так

```
            var r = ((DataRowView)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource].Current).Row;
            var index = r.Table.Rows.IndexOf(r);
            MessageBox.Show($"{index}");
```

Мне нужно наоборот. Зная индекс в Таблице узнать какой он в dataGridView чтобы позиционировать на него курсор методом

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = ???
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Находите нужный tableRow в таблице по индексу
2. Находите index его в DataGridView

   ```
   DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(r => r.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString().Equals(tableRow["ID"].ToString()))
        .First();

    rowIndex = row.Index;
   ```

Comment: получаю ошибку Не удается найти столбец с именем ID. Такой столбец там точно есть и он Primary key.  Что не так?

Comment: Попробуйте через индекс поля 0

Comment: Обидно конечно за улетевший 100

Comment: да получилось. Засчитал ответ. Но все-равно спрошу.  Почему по имени поля  не срабатывает? Я этот код нагугливал. И везде с именем поля. А у меня не работает но поле точно есть.

Comment: сожалею за 100ку. Я с ходу подумал Ваш ответ.

Comment: Думаю из-за каста.

Comment: Хотя бы сослался бы в комментарии, а то он важный сам додумался гридвью использовать

Comment: Никакую сотку я не получил, конкурс открыт. Если вам так важно, можете запостить там ответ, автор переставит галочку и отдаст вам свою репутацию. Я не знаю, как вы хотели получить награду за конкурс не запостив ни одного ответа. Это технически не возможно.

Comment: Ононокак бывает походу не спится. Мне не за 100 несчастную обидно, а отношение. Ссылаться надо на источники данных чтоб не обижать людей которые тоже старались помочь.

Comment: Я вам сослался на полсотни источников на двух SO. Еще раз, договоритесь с автором, запостите ответ, он его примет, и под галочкой нажмет +100. И вы получите свой лицензионный гонорар, все будут довольны, а мне в целом все равно, главное чтобы вам было хорошо, и вы бы про это больше не вспоминали. Драк из-за репутации мне здесь не надо, я не в репутацию здесь играю, а изучаю C# и .NET, отвечая на разные вопросы. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), почитайте еще, как это работает. Всем добра.